# If a Jamaican is deported despite living in the UK their whole life can they live in Ireland or other countries close? like France?

Tags: united-kingdom

If a Jamaican is being deported and lost the appeal to stop in the UK does this mean he can also not live in Ireland/ and Northern Ireland?

Also does it mean he would not be able to move to local countries such as France and the Netherlands?

Comment: Definitely not N Ireland, since it’s part of the UK

Comment: Any Jamaican who has lived in the UK for "their whole life" (and indeed anyone who has lived in the UK for any long period of time from 1988 or earlier) should be aware of the [Windrush scheme](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/windrush-scheme).  Depending on the reason for the deportation, it may be possible to apply for a certificate of right of abode or a returning resident visa.

Comment: You may get better answers if you can provide more information surrounding your deportation and the reason behind it

Answer (score 1):

**Northern Ireland is part of the UK** so if you are banned from entering the UK you are banned from there too.

A ban or deportation from the UK does not *automatically* make you banned from other countries. However the UK shares immigration information with Schengen and other nearby countries, especially Ireland. They will know you were deported, which makes it very, very unlikely that you will be granted any kind of visa, let alone an extended one. This extends to pretty much every country in Europe, as well as plenty of others. Even visas for the US and Canada will be hard to get.

Comment: *However the UK shares immigration information with Schengen and other nearby countries* The UK only participates in the Schengen Information System as far as sharing information on missing and wanted people. There is no mechanism for sharing of people who are are banned from the UK with other EU nations apart from Ireland.